# drawing new lines in an already populated canvas

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

So I got on my grid a canvas which as its background it get a drawing brush from resource dictionary.That not a problem it works perfect …

But now I need to draw an open ended polygon on it , which gets its coordinates as an array of X and Y. let’s say intX[i]  and intY[i] arrays…. So point 1 is intX[0]  and intY[0] and so on ….

And after that depending on some calculation I will get some more attributes and I need to add some horizontals and vertical lines ‘no more polygons’ .
After that I need to write the result on it … so on point (x1,y1) I need to WRITE the result

Ps : is this even possible …. Is canvas a good choice ‘ I chose canvas because the coordinates should be absolute and doesn’t change when window or object is resized’ the newly drawn lines should not delete the previous drawn line or the background’
Sorry or my bad English and I hope u can guide me with something to start with….

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand your need but you could use a custom `ItemsControl`.

First you need an entity to store all the infos for a single data-point, its position and label:

```
public class DataPoint : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double left;
    public double Left
    {
        get { return left; }
        set
        {
            if (value != left)
            {
                left = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Left"));
            }
        }
    }

    private double top;
    public double Top
    {
        get { return top; }
        set
        {
            if (value != top)
            {
                top = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Top"));
            }
        }
    }

    private string text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return text; }
        set
        {
            if (value != text)
            {
                text = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Text"));
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
}
```

Then in your VM or directly in your code-behind you could expose it with an `ObservableCollection`:

```
public ObservableCollection<DataPoint> Points { get; set; }
```

Then on the view side:

```
<DockPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Click="GetData_Click">Get Data</Button>
        <Button Click="GetText_Click">Get Text</Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Points}">
        <ItemsControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Canvas IsItemsHost="True" Background="AliceBlue" Width="500" Height="500"></Canvas>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Template>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DataPoint}">
                <Canvas>
                    <Ellipse Fill="Red" Width="6" Height="6" Canvas.Left="-3" Canvas.Top="-3"></Ellipse>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="0"></TextBlock>
                </Canvas>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Left}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Top}"/>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>
</DockPanel>
```

`local` is the mapping of the `DataPoint` class namespace.

Here are the two event handlers used for demo purposes:

```
Random rand = new Random();

private void GetData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    const int max = 500;

    Points.Add(new DataPoint { Left = rand.Next(max), Top = rand.Next(max) });
    Points.Add(new DataPoint { Left = rand.Next(max), Top = rand.Next(max) });
    Points.Add(new DataPoint { Left = rand.Next(max), Top = rand.Next(max) });
    Points.Add(new DataPoint { Left = rand.Next(max), Top = rand.Next(max) });
}

private void GetText_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataPoint p in Points)
    {
        p.Text = ((char)('a' + rand.Next(26))).ToString();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.